# Moving Moodle from server

Tags: server, config, moodle

I'm having some trouble changing the Moodle of a client from our tests server to their server. I'm getting this error:

"Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting."

I've seen it around in the Moodle forums but I couldn't find any solution.

HERE'S WHAT I DID:

I moved the database to the new server.

I downloaded the moodle and moodledata folders from the FTP and uploaded them to the new server in the exact same paths. What I mean is: our old server was ourserver.biz/moodle and the new one is exactly the same: theirserver.com/moodle

The moodledata folder was uploaded also in the same path: /home/ourserver/moodledata

and /home/theirserver/moodledata

I have also checked the permissions to the moodledata folder on both server and they are both 755, I still tried switching to 777 and it didn't work either.

PLEASE ask questions if you need more details.

I don't really know what to do anymore... I hope someone can help us. Thanks for your time in advance.

EDIT:

these are the actual configs on config.php

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://cenertec.pt/moodle';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/home/cenertec/moodledata';
```

I hope that with the link you can see what's happening and am I doing wrong. [link](http://cenertec.pt/moodle)

EDIT 2:

I went to check the database and it is also good looking. I checked the access to it and it is also correct.

Comment: I have browsed to your site and it looks OK. Can you post an update to say how you fixed it?

Comment: @Pete We contacted the server administration. It was a matter of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the folder to `config.php`?

```
$CFG->dataroot = '/home/ourserver/moodledata';
```

Can the web user access the folder?

For example

```
sudo chown -R yourusername:www-data /home/ourserver/moodledata
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I added some more details on my question as an Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps much, but the only way for that error to occur is if the PHP function [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) returns **FALSE**.

According to the PHP manual page:

**realpath()** returns **FALSE** on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist.

**Note:** The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise **realpath()** will return **FALSE**.